# Is it possible to have Sass output a "DO NOT MODIFY" header?

Tags: sass

Is it possible to have Sass output a "DO NOT MODIFY" message on the first line of each generated css file?

A la Barista:

```
/* DO NOT MODIFY. This file was compiled Mon, 29 Aug 2011 17:08:00 GMT from
* /var/www/test/app/coffeescripts/add_to_cart.coffee
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Says @chriseppstein:

> Yep. Any comment that starts with /*! will never be stripped out even in compressed mode.
>
> It also evaluates sass-script so in theory you can add dates, etc. but unless you know ruby that's not easy.
>
> I've been meaning to build helper functions that would be useful in such a context: bit.ly/neASVa